How to set default prop data in Next.js?
I'm making React/Next app with CRUD.
About update form, I made some code below.
This code is fetching existing data and after renewing the data, updating through api.
Regrettably this code has big problem.
If you don't update input form, the data that is title and content will disappear without trace.
I understand updating data could be done only when setTitle and setContent work.
But I don't know how to fix this code as I expected.
If you only updated the title, the content would be clear after pushing submit button.
Like this.
Before

title: aaa
content: bbb

Update title aaa to aaaa
After

title: aaaa
content:

My code is here.
import Link from "next/link";
import { client } from "@/libs/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Update ({ blog }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const id = blog.id;
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  async function update(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    client.update({
      endpoint: "blogs",
      content: {
        title: title,
        content: content,
      },
      contentId: id
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        alert("Something wrong is happening")
      } else {
        alert("Editing is done")
        router.push(`/`)
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='main'>
        <h1 className=''>Edit page</h1>

        <div className="contents">

            <div>
                <form onSubmit={ update }>
                  <div>
                      <h2>Here's title</h2>
                      <input name="title" type="text" defaultValue={blog.title} onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <h2>Contents</h2>
                      <textarea name="content" defaultValue={blog.content} onChange={(event) => setContent(event.target.value)} ></textarea>
                  </div>
                <button type="submit">
                    <p>Submit</p>
                </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs" });

  const paths = data.contents.map((content) => `/blog/${content.id}/update`);
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs", contentId: id });

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data,
    },
  };
};


First, you need to initialize the state with the default value coming from blog prop object, and when you need to make your update API call, you only update the fields that the user has changed, because your current approach is passing both title and content as they are stored in the state (whether changed or not) to your API should work as expected.
import Link from "next/link";
import { client } from "@/libs/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Update ({ blog }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const id = blog.id;
  
  // Initialize state with current blog data
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(blog.title);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(blog.content);

  async function update(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    client.update({
      endpoint: "blogs",
      content: {
        title: title,
        content: content,
      },
      contentId: id
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        alert("Something wrong is happening");
      } else {
        alert("Editing is done");
        router.push(`/`);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='main'>
        <h1 className=''>Edit page</h1>
        <div className="contents">
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={update}>
              <div>
                <h2>Here's title</h2>
                <input 
                  name="title" 
                  type="text" 
                  value={title} 
                  onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)} 
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2>Contents</h2>
                <textarea 
                  name="content" 
                  value={content} 
                  onChange={(event) => setContent(event.target.value)}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit">
                <p>Submit</p>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs" });

  const paths = data.contents.map((content) => `/blog/${content.id}/update`);
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs", contentId: id });

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data,
    },
  };
};


Perfect! Thanks a lot. After fixing the code as you stated, it works as I expected.
